# Multiply font size of children

Tags: html, css

It might be impossible to do but I would like to add a css (ideally exclusively css) that multiply font size of all the children elements. For example, if you have various font sizes:

```
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
```

I would like to add a class:

```
<div class="multiply-font">
   <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
   <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
   <h3>This is heading 3</h3>
</div>
```

such as all the sizes will be multiplied by a factor. Therefore,  will be X times bigger/smaller than  without the class etc...

Comment: why not try sass ^ ^

Comment: @Hemant not very familiar with sass... could you please develop a little bit your comment? What can sass do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare the `font-size` for the multiply-font-class, this is exactly what will happen, if you use the `em` unit. `em` refers to your font size (or the vertical height of your font, to be precise) with `1 em` as your default size. If you declare with

```
.multiply-font{
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

the result should be exactly as described (with the font size twice as large).

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @j-starick, you can do this with EM-units - as shown in the example:

```css
.multiplycontent {
font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test heading h1</h1>
<h2>Test heading h2</h2>
<h3>Test heading h3</h3>

<div class="multiplycontent">
<h1>Test heading h1 multiplied</h1>
<h2>Test heading h2 multiplied</h2>
<h3>Test heading h3 multiplied</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do that with javascript

```js
  var font_size = $('.multiple').css('font-size');
  var old_size = font_size.slice(0,font_size.length-2)*2;
  var font_type = font_size.slice(font_size.length,font_size.length-2);
    $('.multiple').css('font-size',old_size+font_type)
```

In some cases it can be percentage and you need to improve this code for it.

Comment: Will it apply to all the children?

Comment: While you loop it for its children, yep